# Concatenate Prefix based on ID -TSQL

Tags: t-sql, concatenation, for-xml-path

What i want is to manage to concatenate all Prefixs with the same ID.

Here is the code i use:

```sql
  CTE_1 (ID,Prefix)AS (SELECT *, STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Prefix
            FROM CTE
            WHERE ID = t.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM CTE
) t)
```

The code works fine but when the Prefix is empty it import a `,` and i wan to avoid it.

Any idea?

SQL version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? If you mean `NULL`, then that won't happen; `', ' + NULL = NULL`. If you mean an empty string (`''`) then filter those rows out in the `WHERE` before you aggregate your strings.

Comment: i add another where clause. thanks Larnu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your query as follow:

```
CTE_1 (ID,Prefix)AS (SELECT *, STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT 
             CASE 
                 WHEN Prefix IS NOT NULL AND Prefix <> ''
                 THEN ', ' + Prefix
                 ELSE ''
             END
        FROM CTE
        WHERE ID = t.ID
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM CTE
) t)
```